# ASP.NET IIS Application Error

Tags: asp.net, iis

Im very new to IIS and ASP.NET. 
Im only using it as a script i need uses it.
Ive installed IIS onto my W7 machine and set it all up to use ASP.

However, 
When i access the script i just get an error which is the following:

```
  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 34:     <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
Line 35:     <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="104856"/>
Line 36:     <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="720"/>
Line 37:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
Line 38:       <assemblies>
```

As i say im new to this and i have found a few posts around which say do this that and the other but i have no idea how to implement the fixes. 
Would be great if someone could give me a step by step guide or point me in the direction of such a thing.

Cheers

Comment: Is your virtual directory configured as an application in IIS?

Comment: I have no idea what that means to be honest mate. Im more used to Apache. Never used IIS before

Comment: This error usually means that you've either forgotten to create a root application in IIS (this is easiest done from Visual Studio : Project Properties - select Use Local IIS click create Virtual Directory. Alternatively, you have a nested web.config in a subdirectory which is using config sections which must be in a root app.

Comment: I didnt get the Visual Studio solution with the download of the script.

Comment: http://www.redbrooktech.com/trailblazer.zip   - heres the link to the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is stated in [Microsoft's support knowledgebase](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917413):

> To resolve this problem, remove the virtual directory in IIS. Then,
>   re-create the virtual directory and configure it as an application. To
>   remove the virtual directory, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
> 2. In Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Internet Information Services.
>
>    Note If the Administrative Tools icon is unavailable in Control Panel, click Switch to Classic View, and then double-click
>      Administrative Tools.
> 3. Click the name of the server that you want to configure, and then double-click Web Sites.
> 4. Double-click the name of the Web site that you want to configure.
> 5. Right-click the name of the virtual directory that you want to remove, and then click Delete.
> 6. Click Yes.
>
> To create a new virtual directory and configure it as an application,
>   follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click to select the name of the Web site in which you want to add the new virtual directory.
> 2. On the Action menu, point to New, and then click Virtual Directory.
> 3. In the Virtual Directory Creation Wizard, click Next.
> 4. Type the name of the virtual directory that you want to create, and then click Next.
> 5. Click Browse, select the directory for the application, and then click OK.
> 6. Click Next, and then click Finish.
>
>    Note By default, a new application that has the same name as the new virtual directory is created in IIS.

Comment: If you're going to quote another site, please provide proper attribution. I've done that here, but make sure you do this in the future.